# formatted paste two text files adding a given number of empty lines in one of them via bash/sed/awk

Tags: string, bash, shell, awk, newline

I have two text files `A.txt` (length N) and `B.txt` (lenght N*n, where n is the block lenght) with the following structure

`A.txt`:

```
Line 1 
Line 2 
Line 3
...
Line N
```

`B.txt`:

```
Block1 (line 1)
Block1 (line 2)
Block1 (line 3)
...
Block1 (line n)
Block2
...
... 
BlockN
```

I would like to merge the two files respecting some format and in a way that each i-th line from A.txt would go before the corresponding i-th block in B.txt:

```
Line1 #from A.txt 
Block1 (line 1) #from B.txt
Block1 (line 2) 
Block1 (line 3)
...
Block1 (line n)
Line2 #from A.txt 
Block2 #from B.txt
...
... 
LineN #from A.txt 
BlockN #from B.txt
```

In bash, the best would be to add (n-1) empty lines to `A.txt` and then use `paste` command, followed by `awk` to manage the formatted printing of all lines.

However, I face two difficulties:

- define (with a bash loop) a string made of (n-1) empty lines
- pass the string variable to awk to `printf` it

This is a possible example (N=2, n=3):

`A.txt`:

```
10  2.3
20  0.653
```

`B.txt`:

```
A x 2.5 3 6.1
B x 1.0 2.5 4
C x 1 1 0.52
A x 1.5 2 2.5
B x 2 3 1
C x 2.01 3.0 1.0
```

it should results (format requirement may also need to clean up some column from `B.txt`):

```
10    2.300
A   2.5 3.0 6.1
B   1.0 2.5 4.0
C   1.0 1.0 0.5
20    0.653
A   1.5 2.0 2.5
B   2.0 3.0 1.0
C   2.0 3.0 1.0
```

Comment: It'd make things clearer if you showed a smaller example with real input/output, e.g. where `n` = 3 and `N` = 2.

Comment: I did: many thanks @TomFenech !

Comment: What happened to the `x` characters from B.txt in the output?

Comment: it has to be removed, it is an example of "formatted cleaning"

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution where `n` = 3 and `N` = 4. The `n` value is passed to awk via `-v`:

```
$ cat a.txt
A1
A2
A3
A4

$ cat b.txt
b11
b12
b13
b21
b22
b23
b31
b32
b33
b41
b42
b43

$ awk -v n=3 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} FNR % n == 1 {print a[++i]}1' a.txt b.txt
A1
b11
b12
b13
A2
b21
b22
b23
A3
b31
b32
b33
A4
b41
b42
b43
```

**Explanation**:

```
awk -v n=3
```

Invoke awk passing in the `n` variable set to value 3

```
NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next}
```

When `NR` equals `FNR` it means we are reading from the first file, `a.txt`  (because the overall record number, `NR`, is the same as the record number within the file, `FNR`).

The associated action saves all the lines from `a.txt` into the array `a`, each line being indexed by its line number.

The `next` statement skips all further processing and goes immediately to try and read the next line from `a.txt`

```
FNR % n == 1 {print a[++i]}
```

When we arrive here we know we are reading the second file, `b.txt` (this should be clear from reading about `NR==FNR` and the `next` statement, above).

We use the mod function with the passed-in block size to test whether the current line of `b.txt` is the first line of a block. (If the block size is 3, e.g., we know that lines 1, 4, 7, ... start the blocks.)

If we are at the start of a block, we print the next line from the `a` array containing the lines from `a.txt`. The incremented index `i` assures that line `t` from `a.txt` will always be printed before block `t` from `b.txt`.

```
1
```

The `1` is an awk idiom that says to print the current line. Awk consists of a set of patterns and actions. The `1` here is a pattern that evaluates to true. Since there's no explicit action given, the default action is invoked which is to print the current line. Instead of the `1`, we could have put `{print}`, e.g.

Comment: @gluuke, I've added a section explaining. If you still have any questions don't hesitate to ask.